# No puedo iniciar un archivo jar

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola estoy teniendo un problema al querer abrir mi archivo jar después de hacer el build.
En mi ide bare todo correcto, pero despues a querer abrir el ejecutable jar no me inicia y al hacerlo por consola me salta el siguiente error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteLayout

Intente agregando la dependencia aparte, cree una carpeta con la librería en mi proyecto y no funciona, si alguien me puede dar una mano. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar la librería, tienes que ir a:

```
tools / libraries
```

En la ventana de la derecha, pulsas:

```
New Library
```

y escribes "**Absolute Layout**", luego en la ventana de la derecha, pulsas:

```
Add JAR/Folder
```

Desde la ventana emergente seleccionas el arcivo **.jar** que descargaste, le das a:

```
    Add JAR/Folder
```

Y listo!!